# Having problem to access deployed application in multiclustering kubernetes environment in VirtualBox

Tags: docker, kubernetes, virtualbox

I have create multicluster kubernetes environment and my node details is:

`kubectl get nodes -o wide`

```
NAME            STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION   INTERNAL-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE             KERNEL-VERSION      CONTAINER-RUNTIME
16-node-121     Ready    <none>   32m   v1.14.1   192.168.0.121   <none>        Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS   4.4.0-142-generic   docker://18.9.2
master-16-120   Ready    master   47m   v1.14.1   192.168.0.120   <none>        Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS   4.4.0-142-generic   docker://18.9.2
```

And I created a service and exposed the service using following command:

`$kubectl expose deployment hello-world --port=80 --target-port=8080`

The is created and exposed. My service detail information is:

```
NAME          TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
hello-world   ClusterIP   10.105.7.156   <none>        80/TCP    33m
```

I exposed my deployment by following command:

```
kubectl expose deployment hello-world --port=80 --target-port=8080
service/hello-world exposed
```

Unfortunately when I try to access my service using curl command I'm getting timeout error:

My service details are following:

```
master-16-120@master-16-120:~$ kubectl describe service hello-world
Name:              hello-world
Namespace:         default
Labels:            run=hello-world
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          run=hello-world
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.105.7.156
Port:              <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:        8080/TCP
Endpoints:         192.168.1.2:8080
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>



curl http://10.105.7.156:80
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.105.7.156 port 80: Connection timed out
```

Here I'm using calico for my multicluster network which is :

```
wget https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.3/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/rbac-kdd.yaml
wget https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.3/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/kubernetes-datastore/calico-networking/1.7/calico.yaml
```

My Pod networking specification is:

```
sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16
```

Comment: It is **bad news** to have a Pod CIDR that apparently overlaps your host CIDR -- those Pod addresses are designed to be "fake" addresses for which the cluster has very clearly defined routing rules, but since your Node are 192.168.0/24 and your Pods are 192.168.0.0/16 then k8s cannot tell what's going on. VirtualBox makes that situation worse since you left off whether your virtual machines have one or two interfaces themselves, and what their addresses are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I have got the solution. Thanks to Daniel's comment which helps me to reach my solution.

I change my kubernetis pod network CIDR and calico as follow:

```
--pod-network-cidr=10.10.0.0/16
```

And also configure master which is master-16-120 Hosts (/etc/hosts):

```
master-16-120 192.168.0.120
16-node-121 192.168.0.121
```

And in the node which is 16-node-121 Hosts (/etc/hosts)

```
master-16-120 192.168.0.120
16-node-121 192.168.0.121
```

Now my kubernetes is ready to go.